# Can't compare string with while and if statements

Tags: c++, string, if-statement, while-loop, command

I'm trying to create a command menu where the user will be able to perform as many commands as he/she wants until pressing "q" which will end the loop. I think I have everything I need to do this except I realized mid-way that my professor asked to use string. When I included string into the program, I began to get error messages saying "could not convert string to bool" wherever there was a while or if statement. What can I do to fix this problem and get my program working. Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char option; 
    char number=0; 
    string s;
    string n;
    string p;
    string q;
    char number2; 

    cout << " Please enter a number: "<< endl; 
    cin >> number;

    do {

        cout << " Please enter a command: " << endl;
        cout << " s- square the number " << endl;
        cout << " n- add the number and (number +1) " << endl; 
        cout << " p- add the number and (number -1) " << endl; 
        cout << " q- quit" << endl; 
        cin >> option;

        if (option=s) {
            s= number*number;
            cout << "Square of this number is : " << s; 
        }
        else if ( option=n){
            number2= number+1;
            n= number+number2;
            cout << "Sum of" << number << "+" << number2 << "is: " << n;
        }
        else if (option=p) {
            number2= number-1;
            p= number+number2;
            cout << "Sum of" << number << "+" << number2 << "is" << p;
        }
        else if (option=q)
            cout << "Terminating Program";
    } while(option);
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: You aren't ending the loop when the user types `q`. Add a `break` statement there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're *assigning* in the `if` and `else if` rather than *comparing*.

```
if (option=s) {
```

should be

```
if (option=='s') {
```

note the double =

Also, you need to put single quotes (') around the character choice.

It's a common mistake that even experienced developers make.

These declarations

```
char number=0; 
string s;
string n;
string p;
string q;
char number2;
```

should all be `int`

```
int number=0; 
int s;
int n;
int p;
int q;
int number2;
```

Comment: Also needs to quote `s`.

Comment: The quotations and double = were the fix. However, now when I run the program, it is producing letter answers and "-" signs when i enter a command rather than numbers. I thought it was due to char, so I replaced it with int. Now the program is in a never ending loop.

Comment: @Brandon, see my edit. C++ is kind of a funny language, it does automatic conversions between various 'numeric' types (char is a sort-of numeric type in C++). So when `number` is a `char` and you say `number = 10 + 5;` then `cout << number` what you get is a character even though you did integer arithmetic. So changing to `int` is the right choice. But don't change `option` --- leave it `char`.

Comment: Yup. Made the adjustments and the program is running smoothly now. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Let me answer as if I were who will evaluate your homework. You have several issues here:

1. You are asked to use `string`. Avoid the use of `char` and `string` together.

   ```
   char option;      //  professor asked to use string: (-1) point

   string option;    //  ok
   ```
2. When you use a single `=`, like in `option="a"`, you are **assigning** the value `"a"` to the variable `option`. But in the `if-else` statements you want to **compare**, so you should use the `==` comparison operator. Also, you can't compare a `char` with a `string`.

   ```
   if(option = "a")   // error: expression must have bool type: (-2) points

   if(option == 'a')  // error: no operator "==" matches std::string == char;  (-2) points

   if(option == "a")  // ok
   ```
3. You use `while(option)`, but `option` is declared as a `char`, not as a `bool`. Replace this line to `while(option!="q")` to finish when you enter `q`.

   ```
   while(option);        // error: expression must have bool type; (-2) points

   while(option != "q");  // GOOD!
   ```

   Also, your program will finish when you scape from the `while`-statement; so, try to put the `"Terminating Program"` message after this.
4. You do not need to declare such many variables (`s`, `n`, `p`, `q`, `number2`). Try to use temporary variables inside each scope, for example:

   ```
   if (option=="s") 
     {
       cout << "Square of this number is : " << number*number << endl;
     }
   else if ( option=="n")
     {
       int number2= number+1;
       cout << "Sum of " << number << "+" << number2 << " is : " << number+number2 << endl;
     }
   ```
5. In the form you write this code, every time you type a new option you will obtain an output like:

   ```
   Sum of 10+11 is : 21 Please enter a command:
   ```

   This is ugly to me (-1 point). Try to put a newline (`<< endl;`) after every `cout` lines.
6. Finally, what if I type any other letter not listed in the menu? I would expect a message like `Enter a valid option` (-1 point).